# How to get an element by its style value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following div

```
<div class="timeline-axis-grid timeline-axis-grid-minor" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; top: 20px; height: 369px; left: 53.3095px;"></div>
```

and I want to get this div by its 'left: 53.3095px' value and assign to a variable in Jquery

Comment: Want to assign value? or an element itself to a variable?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: `var specialDivs = $('div.timeline-axis-grid.timeline-axis-grid-minor[style*="left: 53.3095px"]');`

Comment: @Mr_Green - what if I have this? `<div class="timeline-axis-grid timeline-axis-grid-minor" style="margin-left: 53.3095px" />`

Comment: @Mr_Green - I'm always seeing things like that.  My boss hates me :p

Comment: @Archer:thats what all bosses do ... :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
$('div.timeline-axis-grid').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('left') == '53.3095px';
})
```

Comment: But this will return all the div s with this 'left' value know?

Comment: @ssrp - Yes, it will do that.  That's what you've asked.  If you want something different you have to explain clearly.

Comment: Use along with selector to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
$( "div" )
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return $(this).css('left') === "53.3095px";
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

No that is not available to point any selector that way but instead you can use if conditions to check if a particular element has the exact value then do the intended work:

```
if($('.timeline-axis-grid').css('left') === "53.3095px"){
   // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to filter your collection by testing properties that satisfy your need ...

```
 $('div.timeline-axis-grid-minor').filter(
    function(){
      var $t = $(this);
      return ($t.css('position') == 'absolute'
             // && $t.css(...  // Add conditions to satify your needs
      );
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('div.timeline-axis-grid').css('left') === "53.3095px"){
  ////your code
}
```

Or

```
if($('div.timeline-axis-grid').style.left === "53.3095px"){
      ////your code
    }
```